# Filtro de búsqueda C# MVC5

Tags: c#, mvc, visual-studio-2013

estoy haciendo un buscador por nombre con MVC de un mantenedor de clientes 
este es el código:

**Controlador**

```
    public ActionResult Buscador(String Nombre)
    {
        var busqueda = from s in db.PersonaSet select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nombre))
        {
            busqueda = busqueda.Where(j => j.Nombre.Contains(Nombre));
        }
        return View(busqueda);
    }
```

**Vista**

```
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <p>
        Busqueda por nombre: @Html.TextBox("Nombre") <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
    </p>
}
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto no me filtra

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar una librería del lado del cliente _(JavaScript)_  para el filtrado de datos ? o aquí hay un [tutorial completo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: @Pablo Vergara Rain (suponiendo que en su controlador la consulta trae resultado) esta gestionando mal el resultado de su controlador en la vista, no veo como la vista recoja los datos que envía el controlador (un modelo o un ViewBag por ejemplo).

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos el codigo que muestra el resultado de la busqueda?

Comment: Supongo que no te filtra porque el `Nombre` siempre llega vacío al Controller, entonces nunca entra al `if`, debes asegurar que al filtrar por `Nombre` recibas un valor :)

Comment: @Dev.Joel lo que mencionas pudiera ser una sana discusión larga y tendida :D yo diría que prefiero no cargar toda la info al cliente y siempre estar filtrando por los datos que sean solamente necesarios. Aunque también depende de muchas cosas, por ejemplo, la cantidad de usuarios trabajando concurrentemente. Me parece que ese es un gran tema de conversación :D

Comment: @Flxtr es una opción pero no creo que sea la mejor. Solo lo mencioné para que se tenga en cuenta. Y sí intervienen muchos factores.

Comment: No te parece mejor cargar el input con un datalist de nombres y en base a al datalist  seleccionado cargar los datos?

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad alguna respuesta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi opinión soy partidario de utilizar la via que te aconseja Dev.Joel pero ya que estas aqui te digo lo que te deberia faltar.

Primero que nada vamos a asumir que la Accion Buscador hace el papel del método Index por defecto el cual retorna una lista de objetos que será recorrida. ejemplo

tengo un modelo Persona el cual contiene Nombre y Apellidos. Despues de generar tu scaffold debes modificar el metodo Index o si prefieres quedate con tu metodo que tambien funciona. Solo te falta recorrer la lista en tu vista y muy importante agregar el ToList() a la variable busqueda para que te permita recorrerla como una colección.

```
    public ActionResult Buscador(string Nombre)
    {
        var busqueda = from s in db.Personas select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nombre))
        {
            busqueda = busqueda.Where(s => s.Nombre.Contains(Nombre)
                                   || s.Apellidos.Contains(Nombre));
        }
        return View(busqueda.ToList());
    }
```

y deberias tener una vista llamada Buscador.cshtml, en mi caso dentro del directorio Persona.

Persona/Buscador.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Persona>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Buscar por nombre: @Html.TextBox("nombre")
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
    </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Apellidos)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellidos)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Como ves esta vista es identica a un Index cualquiera. Por lo que te recomiendo que modifiques el metodo index para lo que quieres. tambien modifique la consulta para que busque tambien por Apellidos en caso de no conocer el nombre pero si el apellido. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

¿Ha probado si la variable `búsqueda` contiene los elementos consultados?
He tratado de hacer que su código funcione para mí pero no lo logro porque no me devuelve resultados.

Supongo que `db` es el contexto que está como un campo en la clase y que `PersonaSet` es un una clase del modelo. Así que le sugiero cambiar la línea:

```
var busqueda = from s in db.PersonaSet select s;
```

Por:

```
var LstParaBusqueda = objSC.Set<PersonaSet>().ToList();
```

En la cual se usa el método `Set` de `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso debes usar en tu vista un beginform donde el input type="text" tenga el name="InpBuscar" <-- le puedes poner el nombre que quieras te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Buscar:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="inpBuscar" class="form-control" 
             placeholder="Introduzca el texto de búsqueda"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
               <i class="fa fa-refresh" style="color:blue;"></i> 
<input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-default" id="btngetdata">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

luego en tu controlador debes hacer uno de tipo [HttpPost] que te reciba un parametro con el mismo nombre del "name" que le colocaste en la vista al textbox ejemplo:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string inpBuscar)
    {
        if (inpBuscar.Length > 0)
        {
            var RegFiltrado = (from f in db.PersonaSet
                               where f.Nombre.StartsWith(inpBuscar) || 
                                f.Obs.Apellido(inpBuscar)||
                               orderby f.FecVisita descending
                               select f).Take(15);
            return View(RegFiltrado.ToList());
        }else
        {
            return View(db.PersonaSet.OrderByDescending(f => 
            f.FecRegistro).Take(20).ToList());
        }

    }
```

De esta manera haces la busqueda mas certera la busqueda.