# Busqueda avanzada con un solo textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola amigos estoy intentando realizar una busqueda utilizando un solo textbox para el search.

La idea es que el usuario pueda buscar en el textbox ya sea por **Nombre del cliente, Email, Numero de telefono, o Dirección.**

Estoy analizando la mejor manera posible a mi alcance, no se si alguno de ustedes ha tenido la oportunidad de trabajar con algo similar.

No se si usando **Expresiones regulares** pueda indentificar el valor digitado por el usuario para asi saber si digito un telefono, dirección o email.

Gracias de ante mano, cualquier ejemplo o aporte seria de gran ayuda.

Esta es mi clase de cliente pero mi duda es en identificar el valor del text digitado por el usuario.

```
public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string MidName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
    }

 public class Phone
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(20)]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        public bool Primary { get; set; }

        public int PhoneTypeId { get; set; }
        public PhoneType PhoneType { get; set; }

    }

public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int StreetNumber { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(150)]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [StringLength(300)]
        public string FullAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

Gracias a todos

Comment: Hola Hector, te aconsejo eches un vistazo a esta publicación https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86397/filtro-de-b%c3%basqueda-c-mvc5/86560#86560, puede que te sea de ayuda. saludos

Comment: @Vicente Almea gracias

Comment: Hazlo simple: ¿Contiene sólo caracteres de texto aA-zZ? búsqueda por nombre. ¿Contiene una arroba? búsqueda por email. ¿Contiene puro número? búsqueda por teléfono. ¿Contiene números y letras? búsqueda por dirección.

Comment: @Vicente eso es lo que he pensado hacer. pero queria saber si aguien tenia una manera distinta. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes comenzar por hacer una búsqueda generalizada por cada propiedad que quieras verificar. Con una consulta linq debería de ser suficiente.

Para un **html** con un textbox, un botón y una llamada ajax en el click del botón:

```
<input type="text" id="searchtext" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Buscar" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSearch").on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { searchtext: $('#searchtext').val() },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Y con tu consulta propiedad por propiedad en tu **controlador** que te regrese un json:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Search(string searchtext)
{
    //simulando una fuente de datos
    List<Client> clients = new List<Client>()
    {
        new Client() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Jorge", MidName = "Enrique", LastName = "Levy", Email = "me@jorgelevy.com" },
        new Client() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Pedro", LastName = "Paramo", Email = "pparamamo@gmail.com" },
        new Client() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Juan", MidName = "Manuel", LastName = "Pistolas", Email = "jpisto@outlook.com" },
        new Client() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Noname", LastName = "Gmail", Email = "noemail@email.com" },
    };

    //sentencia ling que analiza cada propiedad
    var result = from c in clients
                     where (c.FirstName != null && c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchtext.ToLower()))
                         || (c.MidName != null && c.MidName.ToLower().Contains(searchtext.ToLower()))
                         || (c.LastName != null && c.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchtext.ToLower()))
                         || (c.Email != null && c.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchtext.ToLower()))
                     select c;
    string sJSONResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

    return Json(sJSONResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Justamente eso he probado solo que al buscar Numeros de telefonos o direcciones. Ahi esta el detalle ya que tengo esa informacion en dos tablas diferentes

Comment: Pudieras agregar la estructura de esas dos clases, por favor?

Comment: ya esta actualizado. he agregado las demas clases